# initialization with `auto` needs copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, auto

The following initialization,

```
auto p = std::make_pair(std::stringstream{}, "Hello World!");
```

compiles and works fine with `clang++` using `libc++`.

Compiling it using `libstdc++`, however, gives error with both `clang++` or `g++`,

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_stringstream<char>::basic_stringstream(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)'
```

from `g++`, and

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::basic_stringstream<char>'
```

from `clang++` using `libstdc++`.

My understanding of the standard is that this type of declaration plus initialization should not involve copy constructor.  Am I wrong?  Should `libc++` allow this kind of initialization?  Or is `libstdc++` not correct?

**EDIT**: after you kind replies, I know it is a bug in gcc, which won't be fixed until v5.  Whether using copy initialization or direct initialization, calling `make_pair` always requires a move or copy constructor, which gives error under current buggy gcc.  So my question is how to rewrite my code easily to circumvent the bug.  I have a class hierarchy which has a member of type `stringstream`.  Removing it would cause too much headache.  Is using a `unique_ptr` the only way to go?

Comment: probably libstdc++ has not been updated to c++11

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Looks like [gcc bug 54316](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316), which is supposed to be fixed in gcc 5 (o.O)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: libstdc++ has had a _lot_ of C++11 in it for a very long time (in the order of eight years). But there are still a few holes. You don't tend to get the entire new standard in one go.

Answer (score 2):

That is copy-initialization, and there has to be an accessible constructor to transfer the converted value into the new object.

However, the move constructor should be selected. (assuming your copy of libstdc++ is new enough to provide one for `std::pair`)

In any case, it would be better to use direct-initialization:

```
auto p(std::make_pair(std::stringstream{}, "Hello World!"));
```

Comment: @dyp: I don't understand your question?  Copy-initialization can select a move constructor since C++11.

Comment: @dyp: oh darn, you're right.  Switched to `()`.

Comment: You know this already, but it might not be obvious to everyone: Direct-initialization in this case also requires a copy/move constructor, and has the same semantics here as copy-init. (It only allows using explicit ctors.)

Comment: g++ / libstdc++ still gives the same error with direct-initialization.